# How to apply striped style to a table, two rows at a time

Tags: css

Consider this table:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>First data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the first row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Second data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the second data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Third data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the third data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Fourth data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the fourth data row</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Odd and even rows here does not work.

Is there a technique that I can apply style on the two rows that are connected to each other?

Comment: What do mean by `does not work` ? [(do you suppose they have arms?)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nth-child` formulas to do what you want

```css
tbody > tr:nth-child(4n-3) {
  background-color: red;
}
tbody > tr:nth-child(4n-2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>First data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the first row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Second data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the second data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Third data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the third data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Fourth data row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Actions of the fourth data row</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```